# Graphgs Theory: Tree, 2 paths of maximum length intersect at a point

Tags: graph-theory

Justify that in a tree, 2 paths of maximum length intersect at a point.

Comment: What attempt have you made to justify this? Do you have any ideas or initial thoughts?

Comment: Did you understand what I wrote?

Comment: Wait, what is maximal length, I understood it as maximum length.

Comment: Yes, I understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can generalize to any connected graph. Suppose not, there is a path connecting two of the vertices of the two paths. Pick the shortest such path, say it goes between vertices $u$ and $v$. Then this path only touches one vertex in each path. Now elongate this path by attaching the longer half of the maximal path containing $u$ and the longer side of the maximal path containing $v$, you now have a path that is longer than each of the "maximal" paths.